# El significado de "patata" en "el corro de la patata"

Tags: significado

¿A qué se refiere "patata" en "el corro de la patata"? ¿Se puede confirmar también si es "[al corro de la patata](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cancioneros.com/letras/cancion_amp/2185405/al-corro-de-la-patata-cantajuego)" o "[el corro de la patata](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corro_de_la_patata)"? ...

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: No veo que haya mucha ciencia. ‘Patata’ es la ‘papa’, un tubérculo. Y por lo visto hay ejemplos con ‘al’ y ‘el’, así que ambos serían válidos. Supongo que son frases en donde se omite el verbo y los equivalentes podrían ser ‘(les presento) el corro de la patata’ o ‘(vamos) al corro de la patata’